# How do I build a position index of a general held expression to arbitrary depth?

Tags: expression-manipulation, trees

I have an expression which I would like to make a position index of, which for sake of argument will be this:

```
expr = f[q + g[x, y, z]];
```

Since it's not a list, and I want to build an index at all levels, [PositionIndex](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) is not my friend. Still, I have a solution using MapIndexed that's not too terrible and gets me the result I want:

```
Module[
  {index = <||>},
  MapIndexed[
    (AppendTo[index, #2 -> #1]; #1) &,
    expr,
    {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True];
  index]

 (* <|{0} -> f, {1,0}-> Plus, {1,1} -> q, 
     {1,2,0} -> g, {1,2,1} -> x, {1,2,2} -> y, {1,2,3} -> z,
     {1,2} -> g[x,y,z], {1} -> q+g[x,y,z], {} -> f[q+g[x,y,z]]|>     *)
```

However, this all goes terribly wrong if I try to index a held expression while keeping things held:

```
heldExpr = HoldComplete[f[q + g[x, y, z]]];
Module[{index = <||>},
 MapIndexed[
   (AppendTo[index, #2 -> HoldComplete[#1]]; #1) &,
   heldExpr,
   {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True];
 index]
(* <|{0} -> HoldComplete[HoldComplete], 
    {} -> HoldComplete[HoldComplete[((AppendTo[index$248139, #2 -> HoldComplete[#1]];
  [many lines of garble omitted]
*)
```

I tried the Trott-Strzebonski trick, which did little to improve things:

```
Module[{index = <||>},
 MapIndexed[
   With[{eval = (AppendTo[index, #2 -> HoldComplete[#1]]; #1)}, 
     eval /; True] &,
 heldExpr,
 {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True];
 index]

(*<|{0} -> HoldComplete[HoldComplete], 
   {1, 0} -> HoldComplete[f], {1, 1, 0} -> HoldComplete[Plus], 
   {1, 1, 1} -> HoldComplete[q], {1, 1, 2, 0} -> HoldComplete[g], 
   {1, 1, 2, 1} -> HoldComplete[x], {1, 1, 2, 2} -> HoldComplete[y], 
   {1, 1, 2, 3} -> HoldComplete[z],
   [here's where it starts going wrong] 
   {1, 1, 2} ->  HoldComplete[(g /; True)[x /; True, y /; True, z /; True]]
   [several more elements where non-atomic expressions have sprouted spurious 
    /; True conditions omitted] |> *)
```

In principle, I could probably use a rule replacement to strip the `/; True` stuff, but I don't see a way to do that without destroying legitimate vacuously true conditions (which may well be present in source code for any number of reasons). I suppose I could pre-transform the expression so every `True` is replaced with a unique symbol and then switch back, but that seems annoying and possibly error prone.

Answer (score 5):

I think, `MapIndexed` is not really your friend here, because you can't easily force evaluation deep inside held expressions when using the functions of the `Map` family. The Trott-Strzebonski trick works for rules applied to entire expression, and the way you tried to use that construct could not have worked simply because that was a pure function, not a (r.h.s. of the) rule. OTOH, when rules are applied, they on their own have no information on part's position, which rules out a direct application of TS technique for this problem (pun intended).

Now, to the position index problem proper. I don't see a big advantage in having direct index `position -> part`, since positions are unique and one can get those parts out simply using `Part` or `Extract`. So I will provide a function to build the `part -> position-list` index, which seems more useful (`PositionIndex` is doing that too):

```
positionIndexNested[expr_] :=
  GroupBy[First -> Last] @ Thread[
    {
       Extract[Unevaluated @ expr, # , HoldComplete], 
       #
    } & @ Position[Unevaluated @ expr, _]
  ]
```

The `Unevaluated` wrappers were used to enable things like this:

```
positionIndexNested[Unevaluated[Print[1 + 1, 2 + 2]]]

(* 
  <|
    HoldComplete[Print] -> {{0}}, 
    HoldComplete[Plus] -> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}}, 
    HoldComplete[1] -> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
    HoldComplete[1 + 1] -> {{1}}, 
    HoldComplete[2] -> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}, 
    HoldComplete[2 + 2] -> {{2}}, 
    HoldComplete[Print[1 + 1, 2 + 2]] -> {{}}
  |>
*)
```

For the inverse position index (the one you asked for), simply permute the parts of the list inside `Thread`, namely `Extract[...]` and `#`.

There is a way to use `MapIndexed` to solve this problem, too, but it is way less direct and will effectively just reimplement the above in a more complex way. You basically first use `MapIndexed` to map some `HoldAllComplete` custom wrapper / symbol on all parts of the expression, then use `Cases` to collect all parts and remove the wrapper in their inner parts. I have the code for that, and can add it upon request, but just see no point.

Comment: +1.  In a similar vein: `Position[expr, _] // Query[Association, # -> Extract[expr, #, HoldComplete] &]`

Comment: @WReach Yep, that works too. I instinctively try to avoid `Query` as I don't view it as a core language construct  of the same level as list and assoc operations (i.e. with simple / clear semantics that is guaranteed to stay the same in the future), but I admit that it does sometimes make things a little more concise.

Comment: `# -> Extract[expr, #, HoldComplete] & /@ Position[expr, _] // Association` if one prefers ;)

Comment: @WReach I certainly do :)